# summarise/collapse dataframe by row above or below based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum, r-collapse

Given:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("a", 11),
                           rep("b", 7)),
                 dates = as.Date(c("2019-05-10", "2019-08-23", "2020-08-21", "2021-08-27", "2021-10-04", "2021-12-23", "2022-06-30", "2005-03-07", "2006-03-30", "2006-11-05", "2007-07-14",
                                   "2021-01-21,", "2021-07-06", "2021-09-27", "2021-12-11", "2022-04-28", "2022-07-27", "2022-10-14")),
                 dates_2 = as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, "2021-08-27", NA, NA, NA, "2005-03-07", NA, NA, NA,
                                     NA, "2021-07-06", NA, NA, NA, "2022-07-27", NA)),
                 counts = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA,
                            NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA),
                 var = c("go", "go", "stop", NA, "go", "go", "go", NA, "stop", "stop", "go",
                         "go", NA, "suspend", "go", "go", NA, "go"))
df
#    group      dates    dates_2 counts     var
# 1      a 2019-05-10       <NA>     NA      go
# 2      a 2019-08-23       <NA>     NA      go
# 3      a 2020-08-21       <NA>     NA    stop
# 4      a 2021-08-27 2021-08-27      3    <NA>
# 5      a 2021-10-04       <NA>     NA      go
# 6      a 2021-12-23       <NA>     NA      go
# 7      a 2022-06-30       <NA>     NA      go
# 8      a 2005-03-07 2005-03-07      1    <NA>
# 9      a 2006-03-30       <NA>     NA    stop
# 10     a 2006-11-05       <NA>     NA    stop
# 11     a 2007-07-14       <NA>     NA      go
# 12     b 2021-01-21       <NA>     NA      go
# 13     b 2021-07-06 2021-07-06      5    <NA>
# 14     b 2021-09-27       <NA>     NA suspend
# 15     b 2021-12-11       <NA>     NA      go
# 16     b 2022-04-28       <NA>     NA      go
# 17     b 2022-07-27 2022-07-27      4    <NA>
# 18     b 2022-10-14       <NA>     NA      go
```

I want to collapse/summarise the dataframe by `group` so that all the `NA` rows in `var` collapse by the row above or below it that doesn't contain `go`. In the event that the row below and above are both `go`, it will collapse by the top one.

Desired output:

```
#    group      dates    dates_2 counts     var
# 1      a 2019-05-10       <NA>     NA      go
# 2      a 2019-08-23       <NA>     NA      go
# 3      a 2020-08-21 2021-08-27      3    stop
# 4      a 2021-10-04       <NA>     NA      go
# 5      a 2021-12-23       <NA>     NA      go
# 6      a 2022-06-30       <NA>     NA      go
# 7      a 2006-03-30 2005-03-07      1    stop
# 8      a 2006-11-05       <NA>     NA    stop
# 9      a 2007-07-14       <NA>     NA      go
# 10     b 2021-01-21       <NA>     NA      go
# 11     b 2021-09-27 2021-07-06      5 suspend
# 12     b 2021-12-11       <NA>     NA      go
# 13     b 2022-04-28 2022-07-27      4      go
# 14     b 2022-10-14       <NA>     NA      go
```

I think something along the lines of this will work but the `cumsum` here is too simple for my case as `flast` only works for some groupings:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(collapse) #working on a large dataset
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(var_indicator = cumsum(!is.na(var)))
df_collapse <- collap(df, ~ group + var_indicator, custom = list(ffirst = c("dates", "var"), 
                                                                 flast = c("dates_2", "counts")))
df_collapse
```

Maybe there are better approaches?

Thanks

Comment: Based on your example, you would just need to compute the lagged `var` value per group and then filter out the NA `var` values.

Comment: do you mean: `df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(var_indicator = lag(var)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(var))`? That doesn't give the desired output though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
df |> 
    mutate(across(-c(var, dates), ~ case_when(
        is.na(lead(var)) & var != "go" ~ lead(.), # if the next var is NA and the current var is not "go", fill with the next value
        is.na(var) ~ ., # if the current var is NA, keep values the same
        is.na(lag(var)) & lag(lag(var)) == "go" & var != "go" ~ lag(.), # if the previous var is NA and the var before that one is "go" and the current var is not "go", fill with the previous value
        is.na(lead(var)) & var == "go" & lead(lead(var)) == "go" ~ lead(.), # if the next var is NA and the current var is "go" and the var after the next one is "go", fill with the next value
        TRUE ~ . # everything else, don't change anything
    )), .by = group) |>
    filter(!is.na(var))

# Output:
   group      dates    dates_2 counts     var
1      a 2019-05-10       <NA>     NA      go
2      a 2019-08-23       <NA>     NA      go
3      a 2020-08-21 2021-08-27      3    stop
4      a 2021-10-04       <NA>     NA      go
5      a 2021-12-23       <NA>     NA      go
6      a 2022-06-30       <NA>     NA      go
7      a 2006-03-30 2005-03-07      1    stop
8      a 2006-11-05       <NA>     NA    stop
9      a 2007-07-14       <NA>     NA      go
10     b 2021-01-21       <NA>     NA      go
11     b 2021-09-27 2021-07-06      5 suspend
12     b 2021-12-11       <NA>     NA      go
13     b 2022-04-28 2022-07-27      4      go
14     b 2022-10-14       <NA>     NA      go
```